# How do I ask to have my question moved

Tags: support

This is my question:
[Oldest example of (intentional) PID control](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21945/oldest-example-of-intentional-pid-control)

It was suggested that it should go to HSM (History of Science and Math).  I'm open to that.  I have all of 111 points here, so I have zero powers.

How do I properly ask someone with power, an admin or such, to move it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular users don't have the ability to vote to migrate, so a moderator needed to handle the migration.

I cleaned up some of the comments and migrated over to HSM.  In the future, you can also just flag your question for moderator attention.